# Changing the color property of an SKSpriteNode is not changing its color

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am loading a texture that is originally red for some of my sprites. However, I want to change that color to a white through my method loadPauseIcons():

```
func loadPauseIcons() {
    let icons = ["HomeIcon", "LevelIcon", "RetryIcon"]
    let iconSize = CGSize(width: pauseButton.size.width * 0.6, height: pauseButton.size.height * 0.6)
    var iconY = pauseButton.position.y - pauseButton.size.height
    for icon in icons {
        let currentIcon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: icon)
        currentIcon.position = CGPoint(x: pauseButton.position.x, y: iconY)
        currentIcon.color = .white
        currentIcon.size = iconSize
        currentIcon.name = icon
        currentIcon.zPosition = 11

        iconY -= pauseButton.size.height * 0.35 + currentIcon.size.height
        self.addChild(currentIcon)
        pauseIcons.append(currentIcon)
    }
}
```

This method is ran on the touchesBegan() method of an SKScene. However, I still get a red icon: (the house and the three bars)

[image]

Am I doing something wrong to change the color of my sprites?

Comment: You can't blend red to white, red has blue and green values of 0, use white icons, and change the color to red

Comment: Why does it matter what color the texture is? It will still be red on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
currentIcon.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
```

By default the `colorBlendFactor` of a sprite is 0.0, which means that its `color` property is ignored. The closer the value of `colorBlendFactor` is to 1.0, the more of the sprite's `color` property is applied.